# Can I use SSIS to move all tables from an SQL Server database to an Oracle schema?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-migration

I want to move all tables from an SQL Server database to an Oracle schema using SSIS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess , You are still following the post.

1. Open BIDS.
2. Project ->SSIS Import Export wizard.
3. Data Source : SQL Server Native Client.
4. Select Server Name and Source Database.
5. Select Destination : Oracle Provider for OLEDB.
6. Enter Destination database Credential.
7. Click allow saving password.
8. Select copy data from one or more tables or views.
9. Mark Source checkbox which will selec tall the source columns.
10. Next->Next->Finish.
11. The package gets created in SSIS.
12. Execute the package.

Comment: Hi G.S, I don't think this task can move database from SQL Server to Oracle. As this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SQL11.DTS.DESIGNER.TRANSFERDATABASETASK.F1%29&rd=true) states, the Transfer Database task transfers a SQL Server database between two instances of SQL Server.

Comment: @user133580 : Take a look at the modified answer. It may solve your problem.

Comment: This was of great help, but mine was Access to SQL Server. I created the package as described then added it inside an "Execute Package"  in my primary package (I was doing other things), mapped variables/parameters and worked fine. Thanks!